# Placing a comma in between two sets of adjectives connected by "and"

Tags: grammar, adjectives, commas

Is the following sentence grammatically correct?:
"He was at once industrious and responsible, humble and compassionate."

Thanks for your help!
*edited to include "at once" because the original document contains it, and I wonder whether "at once" influences this?

Comment: Why do you think it might or might not be? What does your research tell you?

Comment: The "at once" does influence it.  It means you're talking about the person having two characteristics at the same time that are not often seen together and/or complement each other.  "at once" has a similar meaning to "both" if there were only two characteristics, except in this case you're referring to more than two in all.  The comma means that you are making two such comparisons.

Comment: Loosely related: [Using two and’s in one sentence, …](//english.stackexchange.com/q/185218/26083#185224 "Using two and’s in one sentence, and starting a sentence with “To”").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is good usage when the two sets of adjectives refer either to different aspects of that person's personality or to different aspects of their life. In this case the first two adjectives seem to relate to that person's work ethic whereas the second two seem to refer to his/her interpersonal relationships. 
If all four adjectives are descriptive either of the same aspect of their subject or of him/her as a whole then there should be commas between the first three and the conjunction 'and' between the last two: 'He was industrious, responsible, humble and compassionate'.